# OrientDB Bounding Box query

Tags: geospatial, orientdb

The Lucene Spatial Module brings some geospatial features for orientDB.

But I couldn't find a way how to use a bounding box.

Is it possible to make a query, which returns all documents which are inside a certain bounding box?

The documents are all kind of geometric objects, as e.g. Points, Lines, Polygons, Multipolygons.

Comment: http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Spatial-Index.html#a--b

Comment: And You can express the BoundingBox with the POLYGON WKT